# What's the meaning of fare to , trucks to and produce grown nearby in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning

from delicious restaurant **fare to** tasty food **trucks to** grocery stores stocked with **produce grown nearby**.

Comment: That's not a sentence, just a string of preposition phrases defining a range of places which provide evidence of Washington being a 'foodie kind of state': *from A to B to C*.

Comment: The sentence could use some commas:  "From delicious restaurant fare, to tasty food trucks, to grocery stores stocked with produce grown nearby, (Washington state is rich in interesting edibles)"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on a misreading of the sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group your concepts within the phrase as follows:

> from [delicious restaurant fare] to [tasty food trucks] to [grocery stores stocked with [produce grown nearby]].

The phrase is structured as though the various types of food are on a continuum, with "delicious restaurant fare" (meaning "delicious food served in a restaurant") at one end of the continuum, and "grocery stores stocked with produce grown nearby" (meaning "grocery stores that sell fresh fruit and vegetables that were grown on farms that are not distant from the grocery store") at the other, with "tasty food trucks" (meaning "tasty food sold from mobile vendors") somewhere in the middle.